# Stuck at deadlock when reading stdout - Popen and subprocess

Tags: python, process, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

Im trying to manage a process using python subprocess module.

Lets say I have python script that runs forever and prints each second `Running x seconds.`. And after 5 seconds the app asks me if it should continue.

I would like to run this process using `Popen`.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'test.py'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True)
# Now the process is running, I want to read all the stdout
lines = []
while True:
   line = process.stdout.readline() # when there is nothing more to read the readline is just stuck in deadlock
   if not line:
       break # nothing more to read
   lines.append(line)
```

but as described on example, when reading stdout of running process at the point where there is nothing more to read by readline() the readline is stuck at deadlock.

Is there any way how we can read output of stdout till the end?

Comment: `test.py` needs to disable buffering of `stdout`.

Comment: The best solution for automating interactive applications is to use `pexpect`.